# Not able to stop nextjs from caching the index page

Tags: caching, next.js, browser-cache

I have made a nextjs application which uses service worker and has an offline (`__offline.js`) page which should get loaded when there is no internet connection. But because Nextjs cache the pages, I was unable to do it. Then I wrote the following code to stop nextjs from caching the pages:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

After adding this code, I am able to see the content of the offline page on all the pages except the `index.js` page, it is still getting cached somehow. How to solve this and get teh offline page content instead of getting the `index.js` page.